# Compare elements from an ArrayList

Tags: java

I have a small problem, I want to go through a list and compare two objects of the array. Each object has 3 elements, I use a StringTokenizer to be able to remove the separator, so each object has 3 elements. I would like to know how to make a method that gets the third element of each object and compare them. And if that element is less than another delete that element and the 2 before it.

I tried to make them with an iterator but I wouldn't know very well that it started from the 3 element and increased the position by 3.

```
Iterator<Integer> it = lisM.iterator();
                int num;
                while (it.hasNext()){
                    num = it.next();
                    System.out.println(num);

                }
```

[image: Visual example]

Is --> if, I was wrong to put it in the picture

Comment: Your list doesn't contain objects. It contains Strings. Define a class containing three fields. Then use a List<ThatClass>. And please, don't use raw type (ArrayList instead of ArrayList<Something>). And use meaningful names: o, d, m, m1 don't mean anything and make your code unreadable. You're shooting yourself in the foot by doing that. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html

Comment: I just wanted to point out that your if-else statement is redundant you are basically doing the same thing in the else code block as the if code block.

Comment: if you compare all elements with each other and delete all the ones which are smaller you are basically looking for the biggest elements are you not?

Comment: @ChagaiFriedlander Yes.I want to find the major element in the arrayList. I also wonder how I can find the minor element.

Comment: @RM take a look at my answer, you can adjust it to work for you, all you have to do is save the biggest elements and you have your list. You can not remove from a list while iterating over it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This only answers part of your question. I could not understand the question completely, please edit it and I can edit my answer.

You should not remove items from a list whilst in a for loop, therefore you can, for example, create another boolean list with the same size divided by 3 and just fill it with true Booleans then set the position divided by 3 to `false` if you want to delete the three items. Then you can create a new list, iterate over the boolean list and add 3 "Objects" which are actually Strings (thanks @JB Nizet) at a time, every time the boolean list element is true. When it is false you just don't add the elements and by doing so you are practically deleting the two elements before that element together with that element.

You casted  a `String` to an `int`, that does not work you have to parse the Strings.

I corrected some of your code and added the boolean list here:

```
    ArrayList<String> lisM = new ArrayList<>();  // here I initialise the list as an array list with strings. 

    ArrayList<Boolean> booleanList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < lisM.size() / 3; i++) {
        booleanList.add(true);
    }

    for(int i = 3; i < lisM.size();i+=3) {
        int m = Integer.parseInt(lisM.get(i)); // here I changed the casting to parsing and moved it out of the for loop, there is no need to initialize it again every single time since you do not change it in the second for loop.
        for (int j = 6; j < lisM.size(); j += 6) {
            int m1 = Integer.parseInt(lisM.get(j));// here I changed the casting to parsing again.
            if (m > m1) { // this makes no sense here because you are going over all of the elements of the list and comparing them to all of them. But I kept it here for the sake of example.
                booleanList.set(i/3,false); 
            }
```

// if you want to go over the whole list you will have to clear the list and start over again for every element.
            }
        }
and here is how you could create the new list without the elements you do not want:

```
ArrayList<String> newLisM = new ArrayList<>();

for (int i = 0; i <booleanList.size(); i++) {
        if(booleanList.get(i))
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                newLisM.add(lisM.get(i+j));
            }
    }
```

Comment: Well, I've tried, but I'm still messing. I'm new to programming and I find it hard to understand. I have created a new class and an object, where I have the origin, destination and weight. Now my problem is to get that weight and whether it is greater than or equal to 15 enter it in an arrayList. And then you'd just have to go through that arrayList and get the biggest one. (And the minor)

Comment: Try drawing it on paper, that way you'll get less confused.